# Trigger onClick(); on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute $(".rope").click() function automatically after page has loaded completely.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $curtainopen = false;
        $(".rope").click(function(){
            $(this).blur();
            if ($curtainopen == false){ 
                $(this).stop().animate({top: '0px' }, {queue:false, duration:350, easing:'easeOutBounce'}); 
                $(".leftcurtain").stop().animate({width:'60px'}, 4500 );
                $(".rightcurtain").stop().animate({width:'60px'},4500 );
                $curtainopen = true;
            }else{
                $(this).stop().animate({top: '-40px' }, {queue:false, duration:350, easing:'easeOutBounce'}); 
                $(".leftcurtain").stop().animate({width:'50%'}, 4500 );
                $(".rightcurtain").stop().animate({width:'51%'},4500 );
                $curtainopen = false;
            }
            return false;
        });

    }); 
</script>
```

Please Help.

Comment: Instead of commenting on each answer, i'll tell you here : `.trigger('click')` is faster that `.click()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.click()` or `.trigger('click')` in dom ready with selector:

```
$(".rope").click();
//or
$(".rope").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this after your listener definition:

```
$(".rope").click()
```

or

```
 $(".rope").trigger( 'click' )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to chain it behind:

```
$(".rope").click(function(){
    $(this).blur();
    if ($curtainopen == false){ 
        $(this).stop().animate({top: '0px' }, {queue:false, duration:350, easing:'easeOutBounce'}); 
        $(".leftcurtain").stop().animate({width:'60px'}, 4500 );
        $(".rightcurtain").stop().animate({width:'60px'},4500 );
        $curtainopen = true;
    }else{
        $(this).stop().animate({top: '-40px' }, {queue:false, duration:350, easing:'easeOutBounce'}); 
        $(".leftcurtain").stop().animate({width:'50%'}, 4500 );
        $(".rightcurtain").stop().animate({width:'51%'},4500 );
        $curtainopen = false;
    }
    return false;
}).click();
```